# what's the best way to query an XML document if you don't know the name of the URI associated with the xmlns attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xml-namespaces

I don't want to hard-code the URI and then have to assign a prefix before I can use an XPath expression to select nodes from the XML document. Is it possible to retrieve this information programmaticaly?

Is this the only way to do it?

```
string uri = xml.SelectSingleNode("*").Attributes["xmlns"].Value?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only good alternative I can suggest (assuming you want to select nodes specifically by name) is to use `local-name()`:

```
XmlNode foundNode = xml.SelectSingleNode("/*[local-name() = 'a']/*[local-name() = 'b']/*[local-name() = 'c']");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the document to find out what namespaces it uses. For example the XPath expression namespace-uri(/*) will find the namespace used for the name of the outermost element.